# The correct syntax for a JavaScript function within a function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, ajax

The function `pagination($total, $limit, $page)` returns page numbers [pg#01 pg#02 pg#03 pg#04 NEXT].

By clicking on the page number (eg. pg#02), `javascript:showPagination('what_here')` is supposed to send an AJAX request to the server containing the returned page number from the function `pagination()`.

Both  functions work properly. When I test the JavaScript with `showPagination('2')`, the server gets this number (2).

What is the correct syntax to send the server the requested page number that was clicked?

```
<td><a href="javascript:showPagination('')"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></a></td>
```

Comment: As a tip, don't use inline JavaScript like that `javascript:function()`. Instead use event listeners. Here's a good quick read if you're interested in improving: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener. It also covers Internet Explorer way of doing that and generally cross-browser solutions.

Comment: Where does your server know, which page it should deliver when you send `NEXT` with your JavaScript code? Do you have a session saving the current page or should that value be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to try this:

```
<td><a href="javascript:showPagination('<?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?>')"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></a></td>
```

But on the same hand it might be more handy to use (with the same syntax)

```
onclick='showPagination(<?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?>);'
```

Comment: This wouldn't show up, because you left out the inner text of your a-tag ;)

Comment: Alright because I was just clarifying the syntaxis. Ty I suppose :P

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As you have commented, I think I misunderstood your question.
You could just try:

```
<td><a href="javascript:showPagination('<?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?>');"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></a></td>
```

or:

```
<td><a href="#" onclick="showPagination('<?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?>');"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></a></td>
```

Comment: I don’t have any problem with `pagination()`, the function returns page numbers with any `WHERE` or `LIMIT` condition.

I’ve tried the mentioned solution (`onclick`), but still the server doesn’t get any value from `pagination()`:

    <td><a href="onclick=showPagination(this.value)"><?php echo pagination($total, $limit, $page); ?></a>

This question is actually about the correct syntax of how to send to the server a result from `pagination()` to `showPagination()` through Ajax.

Comment: I have edited my answer, so that it should now respond to your question.

Answer (score 0):

After reading `"This question is actually about the correct syntax of how to send to the server a result from pagination() to showPagination() through Ajax."` I would sugest you the following :

**Javascript :**

```
// save current page to global variable
window.globalPageId = 0;

//the pseudo function 
function showPagination(id) {
  id || ( id = globalPageId );
  var xhr = new xmlHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/yourPhpPage.php?pageId="+id, true);
  xhr.send();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    globalPageId = xhr.responseText; //sure if the result is only id of page;
   }
  }
}
```

then html :

```
<td><a href="javascript:showPagination(this.getAttribute('page-id')" page-id="id of page here, from php function">link text here</a></td>
```

or :

```
<td><a href="javascript:showPagination()">link text here</a></td>
```